# Size of View in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Here I am reading my View Size in a background process, everything works fine except than sending the un-wished value!

In this down code, I used `(CGSize) -> Content`, and It send the exist value of `CGSize`, which means `CGSize()` or `(0.0, 0.0)`. Which it make sense because it is first finable value, but as you see in the codes I am calculating the needed value and I want send that value.

**my Goal:** how can I send my `(CGSize) -> Content` which `CGSize` is calculated.

***PS: I am thinking using completionhandler on CGSize.***

Something like this but **I am not sure**:

```
var content: (@escaping () -> CGSize) -> Content
```

or even this:

```
var content: (@escaping (Content) -> CGSize) -> Content
```

In this way that it waits until CGSize get calculated then sent it with Content together, as you can see in `(CGSize) -> Content` it capture first possible CGSize!

---

**Console:**

```
(94.66666666666666, 20.333333333333332)
read size onAppear is: (0.0, 0.0)
read size onChange is: (94.66666666666666, 20.333333333333332)
```

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        CustomView { size in
            
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .background(Color.yellow)
                .onAppear() {
                    print("read size onAppear is:", size.debugDescription)
                }
                .onChange(of: size) { newValue in
                    print("read size onChange is:", newValue.debugDescription)
                }

        }
        
    }
}
```

---

```
struct CustomView<Content: View>: View {
    
    @State private var sizeOfText: CGSize = CGSize()
    
    var content: (CGSize) -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        
        return content(sizeOfText)
            .background(
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Color.clear
                        .onAppear() { sizeOfText = geometry.size; print(sizeOfText) }
   
                })
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve? I think in can be done without sending calculated size.

Comment: which part is un explained for you? I would happily explain it. thanks for replay.

Comment: Looking at the documentation and some articles I clearly get the impression that onAppear is executed after the view has appeared but judging by your code it seems to be before instead, slightly confusing:) I have to ask the obvious question, any reason you can’t skip onAppear and only use onChange?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could be able to find the **magical** answer:

```
extension View {
    
    func sizeReader(size: @escaping (CGSize) -> Void) -> some View {
        
        return self
            .background(
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    
                    Color.clear
                        .preference(key: ContentSizeReaderPreferenceKey.self, value: geometry.size)
                        .onPreferenceChange(ContentSizeReaderPreferenceKey.self) { newValue in size(newValue) }
                    
                }
                .hidden()
            )
        
    }
    
}

struct ContentSizeReaderPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    
    static var defaultValue: CGSize { get { return CGSize() } }
    
    static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) { value = nextValue() }
    
}
```

---

**Use case:**

You can use `.sizeReader` on any View you like to read or save the Size of View. It is reverse **GeometryReader**, and I can say it make a ***significant difference*** in your app or project when you need to read or work with the size of a View! Look how much would be cleaner and easier using `.sizeReader` in your project.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .sizeReader { size in print(size) }
        
    }
}
```