# GeometryReader coordinateSpace returning incorrect frame

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, geometryreader

I am having trouble getting geometry reader working with a `coordinateSpace`, I have simplified my problem into a demo:

```
struct AddTransaction: View {

    // MARK: - Views

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { reader in
                VStack {
                    Spacer()

                    Button("Height") {
                        print("\(reader.frame(in: .named("rectangle")).height)")
                    }
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(height: 200.0)
                        .coordinateSpace(name: "rectangle")

                }
                .navigationTitle("Demo")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
        }
    }

}
```

I need to make use of `coordinateSpace` in my actual project since the layout is more complex and I can't use `global`.

When I hit the button the height is reported as 697.0 (the entire screen) and not 200.0 as expected. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

A couple things in your code seem off. First, it looks like you're trying to use `coordinateSpace` to "tag" the rectangle, for getting its frame. That's not what the modifier is for — from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/coordinatespace(name:)):

> Assigns a name to the view’s coordinate space, so **other code** can operate on dimensions like points and sizes **relative** to the named space.

So the `coordinateSpace` modifier is actually for creating a new coordinate space, with the origin shifted over. In this example the `yellow` coordinate space has its origin at the top-left of the yellow rectangle.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Color.green

            Color.yellow
                .overlay {
                    GeometryReader { reader in
                        
                        /// The frame of the `GeometryReader` relative to the `yellow` container.
                        let frame = reader.frame(in: .named("yellow"))
                        Text(verbatim: "Frame: \(frame)")
                    }
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                    .border(.red)
                }
                .coordinateSpace(name: "yellow")
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Text overlaid on square]

Another thing is that `GeometryReader` expands to fill up all available space, and the frame that you get from your `reader` var is actually the frame of the entire geometry reader — not just the black rectangle.

What you can try is putting the geometry reader as a `background` or `overlay` on the rectangle, so that it won't expand it.

```
struct AddTransaction: View {
    @State var frame = CGRect.zero

    // MARK: - Views

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()

                Button("Height") {
                    print("\(frame.height)")
                }

                Rectangle()
                    .frame(height: 200.0)
                    .frameReader { frame in
                        self.frame = frame
                    }

                    .navigationTitle("Demo")
                    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
        }
    }
}

public extension View {
    /// Read a view's frame. From https://stackoverflow.com/a/66822461/14351818
    func frameReader(in coordinateSpace: CoordinateSpace = .global, rect: @escaping (CGRect) -> Void) -> some View {
        return background(
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                let frame = geometry.frame(in: coordinateSpace)

                Color.clear
                    .preference(key: ContentFrameReaderPreferenceKey.self, value: frame)
                    .onPreferenceChange(ContentFrameReaderPreferenceKey.self) { newValue in

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            rect(newValue)
                        }
                    }
            }
        )
    }
}

struct ContentFrameReaderPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGRect { return CGRect() }
    static func reduce(value: inout CGRect, nextValue: () -> CGRect) { value = nextValue() }
}
```

Note that this isn't the most optimal method — its always better to leave the frame details to SwiftUI and to avoid GeometryReader whenever possible. If you support iOS 16, you can try using the new [Layout](https://swiftui-lab.com/layout-protocol-part-1/) protocol.